# unable to run mpicc in linux

Tags: c++, linux, parallel-processing, mpi, ubuntu-20.04

My code was working fine on windows, now that I am trying to compile on ubuntu 20.4; I am  getting this error; I am copying part of the error as there are a lot:
after runing : `mpicc C.cpp -o C`

```
   usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xb8): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_capacity(unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xc4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xda): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy_chars(char*, char*, char*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xed): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_set_length(unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x10b): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x117): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose()'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x11c): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x128): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)':
    C.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
    C.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x30): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x40): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3MPI3WinE[_ZTVN3MPI3WinE]+0x48): undefined reference to `MPI::Win::Free()'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `MPI::Intercomm::~Intercomm()':
    C.cpp:(.text._ZN3MPI9IntercommD0Ev[_ZN3MPI9IntercommD5Ev]+0x29): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `MPI::Graphcomm::~Graphcomm()':
    C.cpp:(.text._ZN3MPI9GraphcommD0Ev[_ZN3MPI9GraphcommD5Ev]+0x29): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `MPI::Cartcomm::~Cartcomm()':
```

when I check `mpirun --version`: I get this : `mpirun (Open MPI) 4.0.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

```
usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xb8): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_capacity(unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xc4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xda): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy_chars(char*, char*, char*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0xed): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_set_length(unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x10b): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x117): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose()'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x11c): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag[_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructIPcEEvT_S7_St20forward_iterator_tag]+0x128): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)':
    C.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
    C.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x30): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
    /usr/bin/ld: C.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x40): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3MPI3WinE[_ZTVN3MPI3WinE]+0x48): undefined reference to `MPI::Win::Free()'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `MPI::Intercomm::~Intercomm()':
    C.cpp:(.text._ZN3MPI9IntercommD0Ev[_ZN3MPI9IntercommD5Ev]+0x29): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `MPI::Graphcomm::~Graphcomm()':
    C.cpp:(.text._ZN3MPI9GraphcommD0Ev[_ZN3MPI9GraphcommD5Ev]+0x29): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNx3sbm.o: in function `MPI::Cartcomm::~Cartcomm()':
```

Because you are compiling with [mpicc](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3.x/www1/mpicc.html):

> Compiles and links MPI programs written in C

but you should be using in this case [mpic++](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man1/mpic++.1.php)

> mpic++ -- Open MPI C++ wrapper compiler